# How to create a scrollable tabs with next and previous buttons in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a scrollable list of tabs with a next and previous buttons so that when I click on the those button I should see the next hidden tabs that were not in the view. vise versa.[image]
[image]

pay attention to the buttons.

I had this so far, but I am unable to catch what tabs are in the view and act accordingly, can someone kindly give a hand.

```
class NewEntryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => NewEntryPageState();
}

class NewEntryPageState extends State<NewEntryPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Tab> myTabs = <Tab>[
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
    Tab(text: 'bro'),
  ];

  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: myTabs.length);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_tabController.index > 0) {
                          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
                        } else {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Can't go back"),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TabBar(
                        isScrollable: true,
                        controller: _tabController,
                        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                        labelColor: Colors.blue,
                        tabs: List.generate(
                          20,
                          (index) {
                            return Tab(
                              text: "Tab $index",
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_tabController.index + 1 < 20) {
                          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
                        } else {
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text("Can't move forward"),
                          ));
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

this what this code does

[image]

Comment: On your back and next buttons, you are updating the value of you tab controller. You should create a scroll-able list of tabs and have the buttons update the ScrollController state and not the TabController. The TabController is updating the currently selected tab - along with the scroll position.

Comment: could you kindly put a little dirt on your hands and provide an answer with some code, also If the last tab(item) is half in the view I want it to be the first one fully visible when the next or back button is clicked @Apealed

Comment: @bihireboris have you done? If yes then please tell me how to create?

Comment: I have, I'll leave the answer when I am free in 3hours from now @ChiragKothiya